# Splitting a list of tuples in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where each element is a lists of tuples.

```
import pandas as pd
data={'A':[[('potatoes',9),('cabbages',7),('carrots',5),('onions',2)]],
      'B':[[('cabbages',5),('apples',1),('plums',9),('peaches',6)]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).transpose()
print df
                                                  0
A  [(potatoes, 9), (cabbages, 7), (carrots, 5), (...
B  [(cabbages, 5), (apples, 1), (plums, 9), (peac...
```

I want to break it down into a dataframe containing just the elements of each tuple:

```
ww = df.icol(0).apply(pd.Series)
print ww
```

gives

```
               0              1             2             3
A  (potatoes, 9)  (cabbages, 7)  (carrots, 5)   (onions, 2)
B  (cabbages, 5)    (apples, 1)    (plums, 9)  (peaches, 6)
```

I would like to go one level further and have this as the end result:

```
          0  1         2  3        4  5        6  7
A  potatoes  9  cabbages  7  carrots  5   onions  2
B  cabbages  5    apples  1    plums  9  peaches  6
```

I manage this right now by:

```
ww2 = pd.concat([ww[col].apply(pd.Series) for col in ww.columns], axis=1)
ww2.columns = range(ww2.shape[1])
```

But is there are a better way to do this. A more 'pandas'-y way?

Comment: `df.icol(0).apply(pd.Series)` doesn't give me at all what you wrote.

Comment: Sorry. Had an extra set of brackets in `data=...`

Answer (score 1):

See below,

```
ww3 = pd.DataFrame()    
l = len(ww.columns)
for i in range(l):
    ww3[i] = ww[i].apply(lambda x: x[0])
    ww3[i+l] = ww[i].apply(lambda x: x[1])
print (ww3)

          0  4         1  5        2  6        3  7
A  potatoes  9  cabbages  7  carrots  5   onions  2
B  cabbages  5    apples  1    plums  9  peaches  6
```