# split pandas column with tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary of the form;

```
data = {A:[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(8,9)],
        B:[(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7)],
        C:[(10,11),(12,13)]}
```

I create a dataFrame by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict([ (k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in data.iteritems()]))
```

which in turn becomes;

```
A       B     C 
(1,2) (3,4) (10,11)
(3,4) (4,5) (12,13)
(5,6) (5,6)   NaN
(6,7) (6,7)   NaN
(8,9)  NaN    NaN
```

Is there a way to go from the dataframe above to the one below:

```
   A       B       C
one two one two one two
1   2    3   4   10  11
3   4    4   5   12  13
5   6    5   6   NaN NaN
6   7    6   7   NaN NaN
8   9   NaN NaN  NaN NaN
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a list of tuples in a pandas dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069018/splitting-a-list-of-tuples-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column)

Comment: @idjaw you are right my question was not very well written, I hope my edit explains it better.

Comment: @Wen the question you mention splits the columns creating two completely different ones, in my case I wanted to use a multi-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list comprehension` with `DataFrame` constructor with converting columns to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) + [`tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
cols = ['A','B','C']
L = [pd.DataFrame(df[x].values.tolist(), columns=['one','two']) for x in cols]
df = pd.concat(L, axis=1, keys=cols)
print (df)

   A       B       C    
  one two one two one two
0   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   7   8   9  10  11  12
2  13  14  15  16  17  18
```

EDIT:

Similar solution with `dict comprehension`, `integer`s values was converted to `float`s, because `type` of `NaN` is `float` too.

```
data = {'A':[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(8,9)],
        'B':[(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7)],
        'C':[(10,11),(12,13)]}

cols = ['A','B','C']
d = {k: pd.DataFrame(v, columns=['one','two']) for k,v in data.items()}
df = pd.concat(d, axis=1)
print (df)
    A        B          C      
  one two  one  two   one   two
0   1   2  3.0  4.0  10.0  11.0
1   3   4  4.0  5.0  12.0  13.0
2   5   6  5.0  6.0   NaN   NaN
3   7   8  6.0  7.0   NaN   NaN
4   8   9  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

EDIT:

For multiple by one column is possible use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
s = df[('A', 'one')]
print (s)
0    1
1    3
2    5
3    7
4    8
Name: (A, one), dtype: int64

df.loc(axis=1)[:, 'one'] = df.loc(axis=1)[:, 'one'].mul(s, axis=0)
print (df)
      A         B          C      
    one two   one  two   one   two
0   1.0   2   3.0  4.0  10.0  11.0
1   9.0   4  12.0  5.0  36.0  13.0
2  25.0   6  25.0  6.0   NaN   NaN
3  49.0   8  42.0  7.0   NaN   NaN
4  64.0   9   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Another solution:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[:, idx[:, 'one']] = df.loc[:, idx[:, 'one']].mul(s, axis=0)
print (df)
      A         B          C      
    one two   one  two   one   two
0   1.0   2   3.0  4.0  10.0  11.0
1   9.0   4  12.0  5.0  36.0  13.0
2  25.0   6  25.0  6.0   NaN   NaN
3  49.0   8  42.0  7.0   NaN   NaN
4  64.0   9   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: thank you so much for this,  was wondering is there a way to access the particular columns i.e. one for the dataframe and broadcast a calculation on all of them i.e. multiply by one for all values in column one

Comment: give me some time.

Comment: Do you think multiple by `df[('A', 'one')]` ?

Comment: Please check edited answer. And if helpful, dont forget upvote. thanks.